# Additional remove button being added to generated images

Tags: jquery, each

I have an image editor that generates a rendered final image. Each image should have a remove button below it. The issue is that each subsequent image is given an additional "remove" button. So the first image has one, the second has two, so on and so forth. This is the code I have to add a button to the image:

```
renderButton.click(function (event) {
var dataUrl;

dataUrl = imgly.renderToDataURL("png", { minSize: "300x300"}, function (err, dataUrl) {

$("<img>").attr({
    src: dataUrl
  }).appendTo($(".result"));
  console.log(dataUrl);
});

$('img').each(function () {
    var $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            $(this).prev('img').remove();
            $(this).remove();

            return false;
        });

    $button.insertAfter($(this));
});
```

How can I get it to attach only one button per image?

***The issue is that it is set to apply the button to each image, which means that even previous images will receive another button.
How do you apply the each function only to the image being placed in the list?***

Comment: So are all the images loaded at once or one at a time?   Either way I suggest you create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate the issue.   Also maybe its just me but something like this would be much simpler using something like angularjs

Comment: I'm using img.ly Javascript SDK to crop images. When you have edited the photo, you click generate, and the image is spit out to another div. Each time you hit generate, an image is created with a remove button. The issue is that each subsequent image is given another remove button.

Answer (score 0):

Quite not sure but it looks like you should do like this:

```
renderButton.click(function (event) {
var dataUrl;

dataUrl = imgly.renderToDataURL("png", { minSize: "300x300"}, function (err, dataUrl) {

$("<img>").attr({
src: dataUrl
 }).appendTo($(".result"));
 console.log(dataUrl);
});

$(".result img").each(function () {
var $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default">')
    .text('Remove')
    .on('click', function () {
        $(this).prev('img').remove();
        $(this).remove();

        return false;
    });

$button.insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Comment: adding `$(this).append($button);});` actually disables the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I would check if the image has already a button attached. Also, since the button is always the same for all of the images, you could just declare that variable outside the loop. I noticed you were also attaching the image to the button and not the way round (which I believe it's what you are looking for)

```
renderButton.click(function (event) {

    var dataUrl;

    dataUrl = imgly.renderToDataURL("png", { minSize: "300x300"}, function (err, dataUrl) {

            $("<img>").attr({ src: dataUrl}).appendTo($(".result"));
              console.log(dataUrl);
    });

    var $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default">')
            .text('Remove')
            .on('click', function () {
                $(this).prev('img').remove();
                $(this).remove();

                return false;
            });

    $('img').each(function () {        

        if ($(this).next('.btn').length == 0) {
            $(this).insertAfter($button);  
        }    

    });
```